# Why the event blur is not working with the function name blur?

Tags: javascript, html

When I am trying to add event (particular "blur") to HTML with the same function name blur why it is not working but when I am taking another function name like blurf or abc

```js
function abc(element){
  element.style.background="lime"
}
function blur(element){
  element.style.background=""
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="">
    <label for="">Name</label> <input type="text" id="fname" onfocus="abc(this)" onblur="blur(this)">
    <br><br>
    <label for="">class</label> <input type="text" onfocus="abc(this)" onblur="blur(this)">
    <br><br>
    <label for="">Country</label>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="">Pakistan</option>
      <option value="">India</option>
      <option value="">America</option>
      <option value="">China</option>
    </select>
      
    </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

or any other name it starts working.
can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Your function is called `blurf`, not `blur`, do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, looks like a typo to me.

Comment: @guyaloni I have removed F from blur but i think its still not working

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I have removed F from blur but i think its still not working

Comment: @ShayanKanwal Check out my answer. Might be the reason causing.

Comment: `console.log(window.blur)`

Comment: @ShayanKanwal Yes, let me do it. But check my answer. I fixed it. As I said you, it's the `window.blur`.

Comment: @ShayanKanwal Let us know if it worked.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman  brother and I am getting your point but the thing is that when I am trying to name the function as blur it's not working but with any other function name its working

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman its working

Comment: @ShayanKanwal You're welcome! 

Comment: @ShayanKanwal Glad it worked for you! 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman  another thing which I want to know that why we don't use blur as a function name

Comment: @ShayanKanwal As I said, it's a name of event listener. In worst case, you can use `Blur()` instead of `blur()`. 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224082/discussion-between-shayan-kanwal-and-praveen-kumar-purushothaman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you are trying to change the `background` try with transparent and also, don't use `blur`, it's a conflicting keyword (see below for reason):

```js
function abc(element) {
  element.style.background = "lime";
}

function aaa(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="">Name</label> <input type="text" id="fname" onfocus="abc(this)" onblur="aaa(this)">
  <br><br>
  <label for="">class</label> <input type="text" onfocus="abc(this)" onblur="aaa(this)">
  <br><br>
  <label for="">Country</label>
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="">India</option>
    <option value="">America</option>
    <option value="">China</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

---

By default, the scope is `window` scope and `window.blur()` or `blur()` is an event handler of `window` object and that cannot be overridden.

[image: enter code here]

So you cannot override any of these `window` related properties.

Comment: for the people who are searching for a clear answer to that question!
Now I understand from the commenters of this question that java script is 
a case-sensitive language So we can not add the event listener as a function name.

Comment: @ShayanKanwal And can't use reserved function names.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much elegant solution for it - instead of using javascript, use css pseudo-class [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus):

> The :focus CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a form
> input) that has received focus. It is generally triggered when the
> user clicks or taps on an element or selects it with the keyboard's
> Tab key.

In your case:

```css
.lime-focused-input:focus {
    background:lime;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="">
    <label for="">Name</label> <input type="text" id="fname" class="lime-focused-input">
    <br><br>
    <label for="">class</label> <input type="text" class="lime-focused-input">
    <br><br>
    <label for="">Country</label>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="">Pakistan</option>
      <option value="">India</option>
      <option value="">America</option>
      <option value="">China</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agreed, but I guess you forgot what's the main question about. The question was why can't you use `blur()` as a function name.

Comment: @guyaloni yes that is the question that why we don't use blur() as function name

Comment: You're right @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, however I thought it might be helpful to know that there is a better alternative than javascript for this problem.