# How to make an element same colour as body and hide something behind it?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an animation where I move an image. I want the image progressively hide while moving with a transparent and non-transparent div at the same time. Indeed, I want that my div keep showing the background of my site but hid the image. Oh, I already thought of an image that is exactly the thing behind it but I don't want to do it.

[image: what I want to do]

Here is the code. I want to have:

```html
<div id='transparentdiv'></div>
<img id='myimage'>
```

```css
#transparentdiv{/*whatyouwant*/}
#myimage{/*whatyouwanttoo*/}
```

Comment: The question is really bad because you ask to hide something behind transparency. 

Comment: @ChiaraAni that actually makes it a good question. Hiding something behind a transparent element is possible and in some use cases needed. As you, unlike others, where unable to go beyond simple imagination and find a solution to this, it a question that actually deserves an upvote.

Comment: At least the way the question is formulates is mad!

Answer (score 1):

you have to give animation to the image, and in the @keyframes you have to translateX your image at 0px (because we want that image starts translating form 0px) with the z-index:0; in the (from) parameter of @keyframes
then in the (to) parameter you have to translateX the image in respect to the size of the div (the size of the image and div must be the same) and give the z-index:-99; to hide it.

```css
#trans{
  display:flex;
 
}

img{
  height:250px;
  width:400px;
  animation-name:anim;
  animation-duration:5s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinte;
 
}
@keyframes anim{
  from{
      transform:translateX(0px);
      z-index:0;
       
  }
  to{transform:translateX(-400px);
  z-index:-99;
 }
  
}
#transparentdiv{
  height:250px;
  width:500px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="trans">
<div id='transparentdiv'></div>
<img id='myimage' src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/18/02/41/autumn-leaves-4633854__340.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: The question was: how to hide something behind a transparent element not a colored element. Also anwser just containign code lines with explanation to make the solution understandable for others is worthless. Its not fulfilling SO guidelines.

Comment: @tacoshy i have edited the code, could you uplift your down vote

Comment: @tacoshy if seems good am i not deserving a upvote

Comment: yes you do. needed time to open it on ps to check what you did. Nice solution, sufficient explanation -> way to go!

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks!

Comment: @tacoshy brother if you don't mind i want to get out of question ban i don't know why it's happened so could you up vote my some post if they seem good in your sight.                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665962/why-the-event-blur-is-not-working-with-the-function-name-blur           and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711843/why-cubic-bezier-in-path-svg-is-not-working-in-html-and-also-is-there-any-sub

Answer (score 0):

```css
#myimage{
      width: 100px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: red;
      animation: whatOPasked 10s ease-in-out forwards;/*forwards required here*/
      margin-left: 400px;/*Used to push the image towards right*/
    }
@keyframes whatOPasked{
      to{
        transform: translateX(-400px);
        width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id='myimage'></div>
```